# Search by size of object type field elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a mapping like this:

```
{
  "post": {
    "properties": {
      "author_gender": {
        "type": "string",
        "index": "not_analyzed",
        "omit_norms": true,
        "index_options": "docs"
      },
      "author_link": {
        "type": "string",
        "index": "no"
      },
      "content": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "mentions": {
        "properties": {
          "id": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "name": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "profile_image_url": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "screen_name": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
   }
}
```

I need to search by the size of the `mentions` object. I have tried this:

```
{
  "filter": {
    "script": {
      "script": "doc['mentions'].values.length == 2"
    }
  }
}
```

This is not working. Gives an error

> nested: ElasticSearchIllegalArgumentException[No field found for
>   [mentions] in mapping with types [post]];

I have also tried replacing the script part with `doc['mentions.id'].value.length == 2`. It is also erroring

> nested: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException[10];

How to query records with `mentions` object size 2 ?

Comment: I am guessing `mentions` is an array? In which case, shouldn't it be defined as such?

Comment: @SrikanthVenugopalan...mentions is not an array, it is an object type, where it is an array of objects http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/object-type/ http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/array-type/ ..see `lists` field example, in array type

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The elasticsearch guide recommends using ***size()*** instead of ***length*** for objects. So try this:

```
{
 "filter": {
   "script": {
     "script": "doc['mentions.id'].values.size() == 2"
    }
  }
}
```

All the best.

Comment: It is still giving the error `nested: ElasticSearchIllegalArgumentException[No field found for [mentions] in mapping with types [post]];`...it is saying that `mentions` is not a field for posts..in searching where `mentions` field exists, I had to use it like this `"exists": {"field": "mentions.id"}`. Note `"mentions.id"`, instead of `"mentions"`

Comment: Yes mentions is an object that contains id,name,prof_image_url and screen_name. Hence if you would like to find the number of mentions entries (where 1 set of  id,name,prof_image_url and screen_name constitutes one entry), then "mentions.id" would be the way to go.

Comment: @Sai...As I had told in the question, I am getting this error `nested: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException[10];`, when I give `doc['mentions.id'].value.length == 2`. I have created another field, `mention_count` and has updated them for already existing fields, and is now using that for the query.

Comment: Just confirming, you mentioned in the above comment that you get the error ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException[10] when you use .value.length. Is it the same error when you use .value.size() ? I just want to make sure since your comments don't seem clear enough.

Comment: sorry @Sai..you are right..when I do `doc['mentions.id'].values.size() == 2`, I am getting the correct results.Many thanks for your help!!.Also can you post the link where you found that `elasticsearch guide recommends using size() instead of length for objects`. I had checked the guide, but was not able to find it here http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/object-type/ . Maybe that link will be helpful for me in the future coding also. Thanks once again!

Comment: For all looking at the answer, I later added a field `mention_count` in the mapping and was updating that field and used this field to search as on the long run the script query might become heavy and slow.

Answer (score 3):

ElasticSearch will not store array of objects like you think. Instead, multiple arrays are stored for each object properties.

So that's why you must use "sub array" instead.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it works like this:

ES version - 7.11.1

I have mapping like this:

```
{
  "items": {
    "properties": {
      "description": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "quantity": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "value": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My Query is like this:

```
{
  "filter": {
    "script": {
      "script": "doc['items.description.keyword'].size() == 2"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but it seems to me that Elasticsearch stores array not as array of particular objects. Such pattern worked for me: I used instead

```
"script": "doc['some_array'].values.size()"
```

this

```
"script": "doc['some_array.any_field'].size()"
```

Should work:

```
"script": "doc['mentions.id'].size() == 2"
```

or

```
"script": "doc['mentions.id'].length == 2"
```