# Count of elements on kibana visualization

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have inserted below JSON records on my elastic index. How do I get count of all the elements present in the "devices" array so that count can be visualized on Kibana Dashboard ?

Filter condition - Devices count needs to be displayed as "4" for SAMPLE application and "2" for SAMPLE2 application on Kibana.

Without Filter condition - Device count to be displayed as "6" devices.

```
{
    "status" : "SUCCESS",
    "request" : ["ABC"],
    "applicationName" : "SAMPLE",  
    "endTime" : 1478772517736,
    "devices" : ["d1","d2","d3","d4"]
}
,
{
    "status" : "FAILED",
    "request" : ["EDF"],
    "applicationName" : "SAMPLE2",
    "endTime" : 1478772517736,
    "devices" : ["d5","d12"]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a [scripted field](https://www.elastic.co/blog/using-painless-kibana-scripted-fields) in `Kibana` in order to get the **length** of an *array* element. So your script could look something like this:

```
doc['devices'].values.size()
```

**OR**

```
doc['devices'].values.length
```

And then you can have a **Data Table** visualization, where having the array count in respective to the `applicationName` by using the [terms aggregation](https://www.timroes.de/2015/02/07/kibana-4-tutorial-part-3-visualize/#terms). Or you could apply [filters](https://www.timroes.de/2015/02/07/kibana-4-tutorial-part-3-visualize/#filters) saying:

```
applicationName:"SAMPLE"
applicationName:"SAMPLE2"
```

which will display the array count for the given filter criteria. This [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17314123/search-by-size-of-object-type-field-elastic-search) could be helpful.